# Pool.borrow ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'

Tags: tokens, aave, dai

I'm trying to borrow some DAI on the rinkeby testnet but borrow() transaction fails, even if I have collateral in the Pool contract. I'm trying to borrow 50% of the borrowable.
Any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

I reply to myself in case somebody else encounters the same issue. Since I'm quite new interacting with blockchains, I discovered there are many DAI contracts, and NOT all of them are supported or work with Aave v3 Pool ...

So to be sure you're using the right contract addresses check: https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/v3-testnet-addresses.
It worked for me on rinkeby testnet